# Comparing string in python

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

I am interested in comparing single digit characters with multidigit characters in python. The comparision should yield,

```
'A' < 'AB'  TRUE
'B' < 'AB'  TRUE
'Z' < 'AB'  TRUE
'AA' < 'AB' TRUE
'AC' < 'AB' FALSE
```

Any clues on how to do this. The strings are ordered from smallest to largest as follows,

```
['A','B',....'Z','AA','AB',....'AZ','BA',....'BZ'.......]
```

Comment: Can you describe the logic of the comparison?

Comment: Shouldn't `'AC' < 'AB'` be True and `'AA' < 'AB'` be False then?

Comment: I have added a few to the original question to explain how they are ordered

Comment: Is this a list you're sorting, or a comparison function?

Comment: No I am not sorting a list. I am doing a comparison

Comment: You guys never saw Microsoft Excel? :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to compare first by length, then lexicographically.

```
def comparison(x):
    return len(x), x
```

`comparison` returns a two-item tuple. First `len(x)`, then `x`. These are sorted in that order

Using your input:

```
>>> comparison('A') < comparison('AB')
True
>>> comparison('B') < comparison('AB')
True
>>> comparison('Z') < comparison('AB')
True
>>> comparison('AA') < comparison('AB')
True
>>> comparison('AC') < comparison('AB')
False
```

Answer (score 3):

Compare by length, then by lexicographic order:

```
def compare_key(string):
    return len(string), string

if compare_key(s1) < compare_key(s2):
    do_something()
elif compare_key(s1) > compare_key(s2):
    do_other_thing()
else:
    do_third_thing()
```

Answer (score 1):

Other answers are cool. This one just returns 1, -1 and 0.

```
def compare(a,b):
    d = len(a) - len(b)
    if d==0:
        if a < b: return -1
        if a > b: return 1
        return 0
    return 1 if d>0 else -1
```